# simpleperf stat -e raw-inst-retired reports different results when I add a nice value

Tags: android, arm, perf

I have an executable I'm trying to profile and one of the first things I do is look at instructions executed through its lifetime.

To do this on Android ARM64 device, I run:

```
simpleperf stat -e raw-inst-retired taskset 01 <executable>
```

As a reproduceable example, I tried `ls`:

```
simpleperf stat -e raw-inst-retired taskset 01 ls
Performance counter statistics:
#      count  event_name             # count / runtime,  runtime / enabled_time
  24,048,456  raw-inst-retired       # 1.284 G/sec    (100%)
```

I'm trying to get this program to have the highest priority on a core, so it doesn't get pre-empted:

```
simpleperf stat -e raw-inst-retired taskset 01 nice 140 ls
Performance counter statistics:
#      count  event_name             # count / runtime,  runtime / enabled_time
  35,967,941  raw-inst-retired       # 1.128 G/sec    (100%)
```

Just inserting the `nice` command increases instruction count by ~9M. This scales with my program (which runs for ~88M instr without nice and 100M instr with nice).

Can someone shed light into this? What's `nice` doing that injects so many instructions executed?